# How to remove an entity class from a Symfony2 + Doctrine2 project?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

The situation I have is this:

When I started my project I named a class "Propietario", deployed my app to a production server and soon realized the name was inadecuate, so I renamed it to "Cliente" instead.

I did all the replacements in my dev environment, tested the app and it works ok.

Now, when I deployed it to prod (cleared cache and stuff), I get this error:

```
[2017-04-20 10:30:30] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception ReflectionException: "Class AppBundle\Entity\Propietario does not exist" at /usr/share/nginx/mecanicos/var/cache/prod/classes.php line 9374 {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class AppBundle\\Entity\\Propietario does not exist at /usr/share/nginx/mecanicos/var/cache/prod/classes.php:9374)"} []
[2017-04-20 10:30:30] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
```

I don't understand why it is still looking for the former class name (Which doesn't exist anymore... I guess there must be a reference to it somewhere but I just can't find it).

Thanks

Comment: try phyisically deleting the folder `/usr/share/nginx/mecanicos/var/cache/`

Comment: Did you clear the cache in production by setting the `--env=prod` option? If all else fails then just delete the `/var/cache/prod` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command in your Symfony project folder:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

If that doesn't work, delete the `var/cache` folder.